# Connecting to Amazon EC2 Micro Instance via C#

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am trying to work around Amazon EC2. I could not launch an instance and all; what I wanted to do is control the instance from a web application.

I have managed to start and stop the instance from my application using the code:

```
AmazonEC2 ecc2 = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonEC2Client();
ecc2.StartInstances(new StartInstancesRequest().WithInstanceId("ID"));
```

What I am trying to do next is connect to the instance and start the remote connection (rdp). from what I have read I need the Instance Address; how to achieve that? is it that after I can get the instance address I can get the rdp file to be downloaded and have the instance started from there?

any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't already done so... I would recommend that you spend a little time becoming familiar with starting EC2 instances manually with the Amazon Management Console (https://console.aws.amazon.com/console/home) and then connecting to them manually with your preferred RDP client.

Once you have the manual process down, you can use the Management Console to help troubleshoot and monitor what your code is doing... One of the challenges automating EC2 is that processes are very long running... (read: slow)